# How to set mfc resource DLL's associated code behind project

Tags: dll, mfc, resources, translation

**Never have known if this is even possible - and if so - how?!!**

But I have our MFC applications separated out into the exe project, and a set of associated resource-only .dll projects, one per translation.

We only need to maintain English, and then parse the resources using a 3rd party translation suite to extract translatable strings, get them translated, and then constitute a translated resource .dll project for shipping.

It's a neat coherent system but for the fact that I cannot use MSVC's built-in MFC editors to connect up visual interfaces back to the correct code in the .exe project files.

If I try to use the resource editor to - e.g. generate an MFC Dialog subclass as the code-behind for a given Dialog resource - then the MSVC environment tries to create such files in the resource .dll project - which is wrong and unhelpful.

**Does anyone know of a technique to get a given resource project to say "Hey - all of my code-behind should be in *this other project over there*?**

Comment: The resource editor doesn't generate code. That's the MFC class wizard. You can use the resource editor all you want, without having to jump through hoops. You simply cannot use the MFC class wizard (or at least I wouldn't know if this is possible). Still, though, this question doesn't make a clear distinction between subsystems responsible for certain tasks, nor does it clearly ask about the problem (rather than a proposed solution).

Comment: The MFC class wizard is built into the resource editor.  Double click on an edit control, and you can assign events or tie it's value to a member variable of the associated dialog class, for instance.
But that class is always - afaict - stored in the resource dll project - and I do not see a way to associate it with a different project.
The question is: How to associate the MFC Wizard / Code-behind to a different project than the one containing the resources...

Comment: And in case that still isn't clear - yes, I can and do have all of my MFC code in the exe project.  I have to write it all by hand.
The point is: Is there a way to get the MFC Wizard to see that it is in fact the code-behind for a given resource dll project?

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement for you to generate a class for a resource using the class wizard. The class wizard is built for the typical use case. If you need more control, you're on your own. (Note, that you *can* use the resource editor and manually write the MFC classes to manage those resources.)

Comment: of course not.  it's a convenience tool.  I'd like to sometimes take advantage of it - out of convenience.

Comment: That's not how the system is intended to be used. The dialog resource should be (as a language-independent resource) in your executable image, with the user-facing strings loaded from the localized DLLs.